# How can i loop over a string and get the links between href that end with jpg?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm navigating to a web site using webBrowser in the completed event i did:

```
void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            mshtml.HTMLDocument objHtmlDoc = (mshtml.HTMLDocument)webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
            string pageSource = objHtmlDoc.documentElement.innerHTML;
        }
```

Now in the pageSource i have the whole page source.
I tried to make

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(pageSource);
```

But it give me exception:

Illegal characters in path

Then i tried this line:

```
var aContents = Regex.Matches(pageSource, @"<a [^>]*>(.*?)</a>").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value);
```

But i there are no href lines in the aContents

Comment: The `Illegal characters in path exception` is because `pageSource` variable is a string with the HTML content, not a file path.

Comment: So funny that you already have completely parsed HTML DOM and instead of using it you grab HTML as text and try to apply regex to it...

Answer (score 3):

Use htmlagilitypack http://html-agility-pack.net

and you can use the library method to load from url - and then check the node to see if it contains the ext and store it in a collection.

```
 List<string> alljpgHref = new List<string>;
 HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
 HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(/* url */);
 foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
 {
      string hrefValue = link.GetAttributeValue( "href", string.Empty );
      if (hrefValue.contains(".jpg")) alljpgHref.add(hrefValue);

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

or just query the links:

```
string[] hrefs = this.webBrowser1.Document.Links.Cast<HtmlElement>()
             .Select(a => a.GetAttribute("href")).Where(h => h.Contains(".jpg")).ToArray();
```